# backing up system image before rooting: please help

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, rooting, backup, clockworkmod-recovery, unrooting

I have a Samsung Galaxy S III i9300. On Windows 7 there is something called a
recovery partition which contains a full compressed image of the operating system
from which Windows 7 can be installed. On Android, instead, there is a recovery,
which as I understand it is a partition with a full micro-operating system
from which can be used to decompress an operating system from an image on
the sdcard and make it the current operating system.

What I want to ask is. I want to root my device. For this, I can use Odin 3
and ChainFire. Once the device is rooted will I be able to go back and
unroot the device? In order to do so I would like to save the program
which reinstalls the android operating system from scratch. Where is
this program. I want to back it up in case needed, I don't want to
lose it or customize it.

I can see my image on sammobile.com, but the download is slow if you do not
pay for the download, and I was unable to download the image.

If I install ClockworkMod as my recovery, I need to root the device first before
installing ClockworkMod, so when ClockworkMod overwrites the recovery, the old
recovery will be gone and I will only be able to restore the rooted version of
the OS. Plus, I will not be able to reinstall the old recovery as once overwritten
by ClockworkMod this old/original recovery will be gone. Is this correct?
What if I want to back up the unrooted version of the OS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, there is no such thing as a "full copy" of the system stored anywhere on the device, as it is with the Windows recovery partition you describe. Neither is there a "program which reinstalls the android operating system from scratch" stored on the device, so you could back that up (installation is always done via [rom-flashing](/questions/tagged/rom-flashing), which takes care of itself).

Second thing is a chicken-and-egg problem: in order to create a partition-image backup, you will need [root](/questions/tagged/root) access -- so you cannot do that backup before your device is rooted (and a custom recovery is in place to provide the necessary tools). But then you no longer can backup the *original* state, as that has been altered by the rooting process (and custom recovery installation). So the only way to have the "real stock state" available is to download a stock image.

However, the rooting process itself is reversible (see the [unrooting](/questions/tagged/unrooting) tag). And with a full stock installation archive (including the recovery and everything), you should be able to restore the "pre-rooting" state. Not having a Samsung device, I can however not tell about any flash-counters which would let Sammy know what "dirty work" you did in between...

Comment: If there is no full copy of android installed somewhere on the device, then what does the program run with "adb reboot recovery" do? How does a factory reset take place if there is no full copy of android installed somewhere?

Comment: @user2239505 - Recovery boots you into the recovery, which is a separate small OS, not Android itself.  As for a factory reset, what that does is wipe out the /data partition, which contains non-system apps, as well as all user settings and whatnot.  The /system partition isn't modified except by system updates.

Comment: There are two main partitions in Android (think drive letters like windows). /system and /data. /system houses all your OS files and typically remains read-only and off limits to you. /data is read/write and this is where all programs and settings get saved. When you do a Factory Reset, it wipes the /data partition but your /system partition remains unaffected (since it is read-only, it was never modified). When you root, it adds the root files to the /system partition, so when you factory reset, those files still remain.